# Graphics does not draw when used with polymorphism

Tags: java, user-interface, polymorphism, awt

I created interface Shape. Then I created two classes - Circle and Rectangle that implement Shape. . Then I wrote a class to use these shapes. When I try to draw a rectangle or a circle only, i see a window with the shape drawn. But when I try to draw both, only the first called shape is drawn. The second window shows but without the drawing in it. How can I get both shapes to be visible? What mistake am I doing? I am showing the Shape interface, Circle class and UseShapes class that contains main below. Rectangle class is similar to Circle.

```
public interface Shape
{
    public void drawShape();
    public double area();
 }
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 public class Circle implements Shape
 {
     Frame fr;
     int r;
     final double PI = 3.141;
     public Circle(int radius)
    {
        r = radius;
        fr = new Frame("Circle");
        fr.setBounds(300, 20, r + 200, r+ 300);
        fr.addWindowListener(new WListener());
        fr.setBackground(Color.cyan);
     }

    public void drawShape()
    {
        fr.setVisible(true);
        Graphics g = fr.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(75, 75, r, r);
        String ar = "Area of this Circle = " + area();
        g.drawString(ar, 20,200);
    }
    public double area()
    {
        double ar = PI * r * r;
        return ar;
    }
    class WListener extends WindowAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent we)
        {
             System.exit(0);
        }
    }
 }

 public class UseShapes
 {
      public static void main(String a[])
      {
         Shape sr;
         // show a circle
         sr = new Circle(100);
         sr.drawShape();
         //show Rectangle
         sr = new Rectangle(70, 100);
         sr.drawShape();
       }
 }
```

Comment: `getGraphics` is NOT how custom painting is performed! See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Please post `Rectangle`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer You typed it slower than last time!

Comment: @DavidWallace I was posting another answer ... had to prep my pretty graphics ;)